# AsyncTask onPostExecute not getting the result fully

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-datastore

I have an android application and I am trying to store some photos as Blobs. I managed to put the photos on the database. But I also want to keep the list of photos taken by a specific user. So after I upload a photo to database with an AsyncTask like following;

```
InsertPhotoTask ipt = new InsertPhotoTask();
ipt.setPhotoToUpload(pic);
ipt.execute(getApplicationContext());
```

I want to add newly generated photo id to my user's photo list. I am doing the following in the onPostExecute method of the above AsyncTask;

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Photo result) {
    if(result.getId() == null){
        Log.i("DELEGATED_PHOTO", "WTF");
    }
    localUser.getPhotos().add(result.getId());
}
```

But I see WTF log message everytime. In the Datastore Viewer at my app's console, I can see that a photo is added and assigned an ID. So shouldn't onPostExecute be able to see the result? By the way, result is not null in onPostExecute. I can reach to other fields of the Photo entity. Only getId returns null. Photo is an Entity class similar to ones explained in App Engine documents. I generate enpoint libraries automatically as suggested. For completeness, this is relevant part of my Photo entity class;

```
@Entity
public class Photo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Blob thumbnail;
    private Blob image;
    private String imgType;
    private Date takingDate;
    private List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    ...
```

Most questions regarding getting some entity by ID was asking about Python and I could not connect them to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ipt.get() after ipt.execute() to get the correct result.  OnPostExecute does not guarantee the full result.

Comment: It seems like get() method returns the result of doInBackground() to me. Isn't that the result passed to onPostExeute() in the first place?I want to return from doInBackground() the photo I have inserted to database. But not my local copy, the copy passed to database. Because database also assign it a unique ID.

Comment: Thanks for steering me into right direction. calling get() after execute() on an endpoint builder indeed gets the result returned from doInBackground. My problem was that I was returning local copy I inserted from doInBackground rather than the one I got from the database after inserting. If anyone is not able to get expected result from get(), it is because you are not returning correctly from doInBackground. Endpoint builders from doInBackground return the database query upon completion so you can use the returned value or in the case of insert you can just use i for side-effects, inserting.